# identify RTF form elements with Java

Tags: java, forms, file, parsing, rtf

I have a set of RTF files. My project is to write a Java program to identify which of those files contain form elements like checkboxes and edit fields. Upon my long hours of researching online on how to do it I was not able to find an obvious way to parse RTF file structure and identify its elements besides the plain text. I tried OpenOffice SDK, Tika and iText but none of them seem to support RTF parsing. I am looking for an open source solution.
I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with Apache POI. HWPFDocument (horrible word processor format) is for Word and RTF, as I guess.